# Non-Coherent Access of Main Memory via Streaming DMA Mappings

Tags: linux-kernel, persistence, linux-device-driver, cpu-cache, dma

### Background

For my research project, I am creating a tool verifying the correctness of algorithms and data structures designed for persistent (non-volatile) memory. To provide a brief background of the problem with persistent memory, the CPU cache is volatile and so pending writes in a write-back cache will be lost upon power-failure, introducing an inconsistency. Hence to verify correctness of such algorithms, I plan to periodically check the contents of main memory *without* snooping from other CPU caches or even the cache of the *current* CPU, and use that as a means of verifying correctness.

### Problem

After doing a bit of research, I found that it is possible to perform non-coherent DMA, but only via Streaming DMA mappings. The issue I am having is that the DMA requires a `struct device`, which represents an actual device, but what I want to do is to just *read into a buffer*.

### What I have tried

I have allocated a buffer *B* and tried using the `platform_device` (linux/platform_device.h) API to create a pseudo-device. I use `platform_device_alloc` to allocate a `struct platform_device` (w/ a NULL check), I setup the `struct resource` to set the `.start = virt_to_phys(B)`, `.end = dirt_to_phys(B) + sizeof(B)`, and `.flag = IORESOURCE_MEM`, as well as the `.name`. I have the `num_resources` and `resources` fields appropriately set to the above `struct resource`.

The result is a kernel *BUG* message...

```
BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 0000000000000000
```

I'm missing something here. Is there an easier way read directly from memory without streaming DMA, and if not, is there a way to create a `struct device` that just writes to a buffer?

### Minimal Working Example

Below is a minimal working example of what I am trying to do. In this test, I wish to write to a value to `testMemory`, which presumably will be held in the write-back cache, and then perform a non-coherent memory-to-memory streaming DMA transfer into `readMemory`, and hence `readMemory` should be any other value than the one we just wrote to `testMemory`.

```
#include <linux/init.h>             
#include <linux/module.h>         
#include <linux/kernel.h>           
#include <linux/platform_device.h>
#include <linux/device.h>
#include <linux/dma-mapping.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");             
MODULE_AUTHOR("Louis Jenkins");      
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Persistent Memory Analysis Tool - Kernel Module");
MODULE_VERSION("0.1");

static uint64_t *testMemory;
static uint64_t *readMemory;
static struct resource res[] = {{0}};
static struct platform_device *pdev;

static int __init dummymodule_init(void){
   void *addr;
   int i;
   int ret;
   size_t size;
   dma_addr_t dma_handle;

   // Allocate memory...
   testMemory = kvzalloc(sizeof(*testMemory), GFP_KERNEL);
   readMemory = kvzalloc(sizeof(*readMemory), GFP_KERNEL);

   // Give testMemory a deterministic value
   *testMemory = 1;

   // Initialize resource to point to the readMemory (so that it will do a DMA memory-to-memory
   // transfer from testMemory into readMemory...
   res[0] = (struct resource) {
       .start = virt_to_phys(readMemory),
       .end = virt_to_phys(readMemory) + sizeof(*readMemory),
       .flags = IORESOURCE_MEM,
       .name = "readMemory"
   };

   // Some debug information...
   printk(KERN_INFO ".start = %u, .end = %u\n", res[0].start, res[0].end);

   // Allocate platform device
   pdev = platform_device_alloc("Non-Coherent DMA Memory Prodding Tool", 0);

   // Ensure that it did not return NULL
   printk(KERN_INFO "Allocated pdev: %x", pdev);
   BUG_ON(pdev == NULL);

   // Configure resources
   pdev->num_resources = 1;
   pdev->resource = res;

   // Add device
   ret = platform_device_add(pdev);
   if (ret != 0) {
    printk(KERN_ERR "Could not add device! error=%d", ret);
    BUG();
   }

   // Perform DMA memory-to-memory of testMemory into (hopefully) readMemory
   dma_handle = dma_map_single(&pdev->dev, testMemory, sizeof(*testMemory), DMA_TO_DEVICE);
   BUG_ON(dma_mapping_error(&pdev->dev, dma_handle));

   for(i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
       // I don't know if DMA will be performed immediately, so I poll on it a bit...
       if (readMemory == 0) {
           __asm__ __volatile__ ("NOP");
       } else {
           break;
       }
   }

   // Debug information... Prints out whether we read the value from CPU Cache or not 
   printk(KERN_INFO "testMemory = %d, readMemory = %d", *testMemory, *readMemory);
   dma_unmap_single(&pdev->dev, dma_handle, size, DMA_TO_DEVICE);

   return 0;
}

static void __exit dummymodule_exit(void){
   kvfree(testMemory);
   kvfree(readMemory);
   platform_device_unregister(pdev);
}

module_init(dummymodule_init);
module_exit(dummymodule_exit);
```

Comment: please, provide a complete minimal example (code)

Comment: @AlexHoppus I have done exactly as asked, a minimal working example has been provided that shows the issue of it raising a kernel BUG.

Comment: While writing this I realize now that I need to inject a `wbinvd` assembly instruction after initializing both `readMemory` and `testMemory` so that they are indeed in memory.